# How to name a model something like FileURL

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I want to create a rails' model like FileURL without having to name the file file_u_r_l.rb. How does one go about doing something like this? I understand that you can set table name explicitly but how does one override the default filename to classname mapping?

Thanks
Prateek

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to do anything. Rails' .underscore method translates 'FileURL' to 'file_url', and will look for a file with the same base name in the load path.

If ActiveRecord does not guess the correct table name, use set_table_name:

```
class FileURL < ActiveRecord::Base
  set_table_name "file_urls"
  ..
end
```

Comment: That works for setting table name but I am not sure if that will  work for filename -> classname. I am trying to create a class called IMAPMbox but unless I name the file i_m_a_p_mbox.rb, rails throws a "Expected blah to define blah" exception.

Comment: That's a result of lazy loading.  You could always just explicitly require the file first so the constant is already defined.  Seems odd that it would expect i_m_a_p_mbox.rb, I've never seen it do that before.

Comment: I think you are right. There was something funny going on between factory_girl, rails and rspec. I have it all sorted out with a sane filename like imap_mbox.rb but something like Factory.define :i_m_a_p_mbox !!

Answer (score 2):

Ask yourself whether this is really a requirement in the first place. In general, you're best off going with the Ruby (and Rails) conventions rather than fighting them. Why not just name the model class FileUrl?